# ASP.NET, OWIN, and self hosted web interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to develop a web browser based interface that can be accessed locally and remotely for a C# console application. I would love this to be a light weight, self hosted app if possible (as long as that means it can be accessed over the web).

I am confused about the differences of

1. Web API
2. OWIN
3. Katana

I started a [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) tutorial which led to an [OWIN](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api) tutorial which led to a [Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana) introduction. I'm not sure now what is the right path.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, you could also consider a NancyFX-based stack: http://nancyfx.org/ / https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation .. You can run self-hosted Nancy with or without Owin. At this point in time, it's a lot of mix-n-match when going for web in .Net. I've personally found rhe easiest way to get going with self-hosted web in .Net is self-hosted Nancy: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Self-Hosting-Nancy - though stuff like SignalR won't work with this approach and YMMV etc.

Comment: Note that most variants which call themselves "self hosting" are still using the central http.sys with the associated disadvantages. There exists a proper self hosting implementation, (http server implemented in C#) but I forgot its name.